# Repeating Javascript Animations?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm trying to make a div go up, down, up again, down again, etc. until you click on it. This is what I've got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fun with animations dude</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="moving">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var moving = document.getElementById("moving");
        var mMargin = moving.style.marginTop | 0;
        var moving = false;

        moving.onclick = start;

        function start() {
            if (moving == false) {
                moving = true;
                move();
                window.alert("Start!");
            }

            else {
                 moving = false;
                 window.alert("Aww...");
            }
        }


        function move() {
            if (moving) {
                if (mMargin < 700) {
                    mMargin += 10;
                    moving.style.marginTop = mMargin + "px";
                    setTimeout(move, 20);
                }

                else {
                    mMargin -= 10;
                    moving.style.marginTop = mMargin + "px";
                    setTimeout(move, 20);
                }
            }    
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was actually quite proud of myself for a while, until it didn't work... As you can see, I made an attempt at troubleshooting by adding those alert boxes. Neither of them were triggered, so right now it's a problem with the initial stuff, although there may be other errors as well. No errors in the console. Advice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first and third local variables are both called `moving`. Renaming the second to `isMoving` (and updating any mentions of this variable) causes the alerts to show as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Hippydog's answer got me past the first part. I then realized I had to add another variable to keep the div from spazing out at the bottom of the first run. I just wanted to post what worked for anyone else looking at this for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fun with animations dude</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="moving">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var moving = document.getElementById("moving");
        var mMargin = moving.style.marginTop | 0;
        var isMoving = false;
        var movingDown = true;

        moving.onclick = start;

        function start() {
            if (isMoving == false) {
                isMoving = true;
                move();
            }

            else {
                isMoving = false;
            }
        }


        function move() {
            if (isMoving) {
                if (movingDown) {
                    mMargin += 10;
                    moving.style.marginTop = mMargin + "px";
                    if (mMargin >= 1000) {
                        movingDown = false;
                    }
                    setTimeout(move, 20);
                }

                else {
                    mMargin -= 10;
                    moving.style.marginTop = mMargin + "px";
                    if (mMargin <= 0) {
                        movingDown = true;
                    }
                    setTimeout(move, 20);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If any more experienced coders find some unforseen problem with this script, feel free to let me know.